# Magento 2. Sales -> Invoices - How to set Filter in Invoice Grid?

Tags: sales-order, invoice, magento-2.1

I have invoice id- 0000017 and order id-12 but this order 3 items so we are create 3 invoice like 0000017,0000018,0000019.Invoice grid in I have set filter like display only 0000017 invoice.how to set filter and which file? thanx in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');

// add bootstrap
$bootstraps = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$object_Manager = $bootstraps->getObjectManager();

$app_state = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$app_state->setAreaCode('frontend');

// get date 
$today_date = date("m/d/Y");
$added_date = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("+17 day"));

$set_product = $object_Manager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');

try{
    $set_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
    $set_product->setAttributeSetId(4);
    $set_product->setTypeId('simple');
    $set_product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')); 
    // time of product creation
    $set_product->setName('Test Sample Products'); 
    // add Name of Product
    $set_product->setSku('add-sku-1');
    // add sku hear
    $set_product->setWeight(1.0000);
    // add weight of product
    $set_product->setStatus(1);
    $category_id= array('3,4');
    // add your catagory id
    $set_product->setCategoryIds($category_id); 
    // Product Category
    $set_product->setTaxClassId(0); 
    // type of tax class 
    // (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
    $set_product->setVisibility(4); 
    // catalog and search visibility
    $set_product->setManufacturer(); 
    // manufacturer id
    $set_product->setColor(24);
    $set_product->setNewsFromDate($today_date); 
    // product set as new from
    $set_product->setNewsToDate($added_date); 
    /* // add image path hear
    $set_product->setImage('/testimg/test.jpg');
    // add small image path hear
    $set_product->setSmallImage('/testimg/test1.jpg');
    // add Thumbnail image path hear
    $set_product->setThumbnail('/testimg/test2.jpg');
    // product set as new to
     */$set_product->setCountryOfManufacture('AF'); 
    // country of manufacture (2-letter country code)
    $set_product->setPrice(100.99) ;
    // price in form 100.99
    $set_product->setCost(88.33); 
    // price in form 88.33
    $set_product->setSpecialPrice(99.85); 
    // special price in form 99.85
    $set_product->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2016'); 
    // special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
    $set_product->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2018'); 
    // special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
    $set_product->setMsrpEnabled(1); 
    // enable MAP
    $set_product->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1); 
    // display actual price 
    // (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
    $set_product->setMsrp(99.99); 
    // Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
    $set_product->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2');
    $set_product->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2');
    $set_product->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2');
    $set_product->setDescription('This is a long description');
    $set_product->setShortDescription('This is a short description');
    $set_product->setStockData(
        array(
        'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, 
        // checkbox for 'Use config settings' 
        'manage_stock' => 1, // manage stock
        'min_sale_qty' => 1, // Shopping Cart Minimum Qty Allowed 
        'max_sale_qty' => 2, // Shopping Cart Maximum Qty Allowed
        'is_in_stock' => 1, // Stock Availability of product
        'qty' => 100 // qty of product
        )
    );

    $obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem */
    $filesystem = $obj->create('Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface $mediaDirectory */
    $mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    $mediaPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath();

    $mainImage = $mediaPath.'testimg/test.jpg';
    $mainImage1 = $mediaPath.'testimg/test1.jpg';
    $mainImage2 = $mediaPath.'testimg/test2.jpg';
    $set_product->setImage(
                $mainImage
            )
            ->setSmallImage(
                $mainImage1
            )
            ->setThumbnail(
                $mainImage2
            )
            ->addImageToMediaGallery(
              $mainImage,
                null,
                false,
                false
            )->addImageToMediaGallery(
                $mainImage1,
                null,
                false,
                false
            )->addImageToMediaGallery(
                $mainImage2,
                ['thumbnail'],
                false,
                false
            );
     $set_product->save();
    // get id of product
    $get_product_id = $set_product->getId();
    echo "Upload simple product id :: ".$get_product_id."\n";
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: https://www.maximehuran.fr/en/create-a-cron-job-with-magento-2/